# How to manipulate JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there was any way to manipulate JavaScript execution on predetermined action on a certain website.

Thus meaning if there will be an action on mouse hover, is there a way to bypass the Javascript execution?

Thank you on your time,
bojanski

Comment: Do you simply mean override a core JS function such as alert()?  I'm not sure I understand your requirements with the "bypass" terminology.

Comment: What is the context? As you are mentioning 'certain website', how are you including the javascript? What action is it that you want not to run (bypass)?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function on hover like so:

```
function myHover(e) { ... }
```

And you listen for hover on a node like this:

```
myNode.addEventListener('click', myHover, false);
```

Then to remove the listener, remove it with the same arguments as you created it, except with `removeEventListener`:

```
myNode.removeEventListener('click', myHover, false);
```